# preg_replace link relative path to absolute path

Tags: php

i have the following code to add domain name if not exists to change all relative path to absolute path in a string.

```
preg_replace("/(href|src)\=\"([^(http|https|#|ftp)])(\/)?/", "$1=\"$domain$2", $st);
```

String values

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/test.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/asset/css/two.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="//upload.com/css/test3.css">
```

i need to ignore link stating with "//" as it is. how to add this in preg_replace()
for example if the link is //somelink/somedir it should not be modified.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pattern to this should do the trick

`preg_replace("/(href|src)\=\"([^(http|https|#|ftp|\/\/)])(\/)?/", "$1=\"$domain$2", $st);`

Comment: id gives error sir  Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '\'

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed some slashes. Just updated my answer above, it should work now!

Comment: it not changing single /.